# Trasact SQL String Stopped working abruptly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2008

I have two databases, made in VS 2008 team sys.

Both have btn click events, the server side code connects and executes t sql select statements. But recently, this one does not pull from the SQL table, the morning of it functioned for 2.5 hours, and crapped out. No reason or errors given, it throws our default javascript error, the TSQL statement quit, and its functioned fine. Anyone experience this? The other Dbase just throws, invalid attempt to read, the read method has been called, but i believe it to be something with these sql statements. Syntax is good, query analyzer checks out, are the databases not connecting to the SQL tables, why do they not search, find, what i can find by manually querying....VS does not update html changes to solutions after rebuild or Build, debugging

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DOC_TRACKER"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string strsql = "SELECT SSN, LAST_NAME AS [LAST NAME], FIRST_NAME AS [FIRST   
            NAME], MIDDLE_INITIAL AS [MIDDLE INITIAL], RANK, DOCUMENT_TYPE, RUC, 
            JOINED_DATE, EAS, RUC  FROM TBL_DOC WHERE (SSN = '" + TxtSSN.Text + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, connection);
            SqlDataReader objreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (objreader.HasRows)
```

Comment: connection.State should be analyzed after Open(). And what did you see in SQL Profiler?

Comment: Perfect SQL injection opportunity. Please look into using [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

Comment: I noticed a stored procedure not referenced in the server side code, execcuting after the btn click event, it begins, no errors, says batch complete in the tracer, then sp_reset_connection exec's checking my creditals against user tables, could this not allow the queried info to post and throw the invaild attempt to read data issue?

Comment: you really have a newline in a column alias?

Comment: Yes, i take back the query analyzer statement, the tSQL select will not pull individuals from the identified table, while they are present. It pulls for some persons, but all are present. How can i find this error, profiler shows no errors, and the select pulls nothing for some, and desired data for others?